# How to use firebase authentication in an other firebase project

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have two firebase projects F1 and F2. I am using a password-based authentication to identify users on F1. I am looking to identify same users in F2. So I am thinking to the following scenario based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37548567/how-to-validate-an-authentication-token-against-firebase) :

```
Client --------- authenticates with email password --------->> Firebase F1
Client <<----------------- get auth token -------------------- Firebase F1
Client ------ custom authenticates with returned token ----->> Firebase F2
  * Firebase F2    <<----------  check auth token    ------------- App Server (NodeJs)    
         App Server  <<---------- validates auth token ------------ Firebase F1
```

Is it possible to configure a server hook (in this case the app server) where firebase (F2) checks if a custom token is valid or not (line *)?

In case this is possible, how to accomplish this?
In case this is not possible, please is there any way to authenticate the same user (same uid) in different Firebase projects?

Comment: You can specify rules in your database so that the users from F1 can write, read or validate in F2. If this is helpful i can show you how to accomplish it.

Comment: That exactly what I am looking for. my problem is to have the same uid for the same user on both F1 and F2, or any alternative.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here [firebase rules: how to restrict access based on user role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38725549/firebase-rules-how-to-restrict-access-based-on-user-role).

You can set the rule as follows:

```
"Node": {
    "$field": {
        ".read": root.child('Projects/' + data.child('project').val() + '/Members/' + auth.uid).exists()",
        ".write": //same here
    }
}
```

Basically what it does it checks if you have an info of this user in the db. Hope this helps.

Comment: What I mean by project is global firebase/google project (a completally different firebase instance) not only a path in the same firebase database. So what I am looking for is to use the "auth.uid == data.val()" rule in both databases and the user should have the same uid.